# VBA Userform and calling subs in sheets?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

Is there a way I can call my subs on sheet from Userform?

I have a userform which calls Main , Main is a sub on sheet1. but it searches for main on module. Any idea how to call?.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sub would have to be public, and you would have to qualify the reference with the name of the sheet, e.g. `Sheet1.Main` instead of just `Main`.